# Spring Boot oauth2 with local user database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implemented OIDC authentication in my Spring Boot web application by adding the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` dependency and configuring OAuth2 client settings in `application.properties`.

In the [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) guide there is a section "How to Add a Local User Database":

> How to Add a Local User Database
>
> Many applications need to hold data
> about their users locally, even if authentication is delegated to an
> external provider. We don’t show the code here, but it is easy to do
> in two steps.
>
> 1. Choose a backend for your database, and set up some repositories
>    (using Spring Data, say) for a custom User object that suits your
>    needs and can be populated, fully or partially, from external
>    authentication.
> 2. Implement and expose OAuth2UserService to call the Authorization
>    Server as well as your database. Your implementation can delegate to
>    the default implementation, which will do the heavy lifting of calling
>    the Authorization Server. Your implementation should return something
>    that extends your custom User object and implements OAuth2User.
>
> Hint: add a field in the User object to link to a unique identifier in
> the external provider (not the user’s name, but something that’s
> unique to the account in the external provider).

I have searched a bit but I have not found a code example for the scenario described in the excerpt.

What is the best way to implement the scenario above?

I guess the main parts would be:

- On OIDC login, automatically create a user in the database if it does not exist
- The web application controller methods have access to the database object that represents the  logged-in user

*Update:*

The guide has [a github issue comment](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/issues/41#issuecomment-253157521) that suggests to look at the  `custom-error` sample from the guide's [source code](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/blob/c6f47f0f952732f2379a87a7dd7f0917dd6c51a1/custom-error/src/main/java/com/example/SocialApplication.java#L62). I guess the first part (on OIDC login, automatically create a user if one does not exist) can be done after the call to `DefaultOAuth2UserService().loadUser(request)`. But what about the second part - how can my custom db-backed-user-object be made available to my web application's controller methods?

```
@Bean
public OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oauth2UserService(WebClient rest) {
    DefaultOAuth2UserService delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
    return request -> {
        OAuth2User user = delegate.loadUser(request);
        if (!"github".equals(request.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId())) {
            return user;
        }

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = new OAuth2AuthorizedClient
                (request.getClientRegistration(), user.getName(), request.getAccessToken());
        String url = user.getAttribute("organizations_url");
        List<Map<String, Object>> orgs = rest
                .get().uri(url)
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(client))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(List.class)
                .block();

        if (orgs.stream().anyMatch(org -> "spring-projects".equals(org.get("login")))) {
            return user;
        }

        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "Not in Spring Team", ""));
    };
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [custom user sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/user-details-service/custom-user). You can think of your `OAuth2UserService` as the  `UserDetailsService` in the example.

Comment: Great, I will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @codeape were you able to proceed? Can you share your learning / any tutorial link?

Comment: I rewrote the application using javalin (https://javalin.io/) instead of Spring Boot. I do the OIDC authentication using https://www.pac4j.org/

Answer (score 1):

Github uses `OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User>` what you need is `OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser>`. So
did you try creating another `@Bean` which plugs into the correct place spring expects?

If not, create one like this

```
  @Bean
  public OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
    final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();
    return (userRequest) -> {
      // Delegate to the default implementation for loading a user
      OidcUser user = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
      log.info("User from oauth server: " + user);
      //OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = userRequest.getAccessToken();
      //Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
      //Fetch the authority information from the protected resource using accessToken
      //Map the authority information to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities
      //Create a copy of user using mappedAuthorities
      //Insert/update local DB
      //user = new DefaultOidcUser(mappedAuthorities, user.getIdToken(), user.getUserInfo());
      return user;
    };
  }
```